# How do you create a new folder in a Devtable.com project?

Tags: cloud

Either DevTable has a huge usability issue, or I am having a mental breakdown...  There seems to be no way to create new folders on the cloud IDE site devtable.  Default projcet types do have folders, so there must be a way, but there is no button anywhere to create a new one (or these mountain dews are starting to fry my brain.

Answer (score 0):

> DevTable co-founder here, as of right now it is a pain to create a new folder, and we know it!  We are working on getting support for true folders in the system.  Originally we didn't support folders at all, trying to move to a more modern system of tagging, but downstream tools and users absolutely demanded them.  Our current folder system is purely a representation of the names in the file tree, much like how git works internally.  We can't currently represent an empty folder, so you can't create a folder from the UI.  When we fix the former, it will be easy to fix the latter.
>
> That being said, to create a new folder, and a new file that goes in it simultaneously, just add your folder name to the beginning of the filename, e.g. `new_foldername/index.html`.  Then this folder will be represented in the UI like any other.
>
> I will update this post once we have empty folder support, and the UI for creating them.

This is now fixed in production. You can create a folder from the project view, as well as from the tree view that is available on the right toolbar when you're editing a file. Happy hacking!